# How to add newline character with trailing spaces with printf?

Tags: bash, printf

I have the following printf command that works correctly adding 5 spaces after the string `ABC` and then prints string "DEF".

```
printf '%s%*s' "ABC" 5 '' "DEF"
```

I'd like to add a newline character at the end, after the string `DEF`, but I don't know how to do it. I've tried without success in these ways:

```
user /d
$ printf '%s%*s' "ABC" 5 '' "DEF\n"
ABC     DEF\n

user /d
$ printf '%s%*s\n' "ABC" 5 '' "DEF"
ABC
DEF
```

How should be done? thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `$'\n'` to get a newline:

```
printf '%s%*s' "ABC" 5 '' $'DEF\n'
```

It didn't work with

```
printf '%s%*s\n' "ABC" 5 '' "DEF"
```

because `printf` format is one short of total arguments. First `%s` is used for `ABC` and then `%*s` is used to output 5 spaces. But there is no format for `DEF` hence `\n` is appended to both the arguments.

Comment: @anubhva. Thanks for the help. It works. One question: Why does this work `printf '%s\n' "ABC" but in this case the newline doesn't work `printf '%s%*s\n' "ABC" 5 '' "DEF"`?
`

Comment: You may also use: `printf '%s%*sDEF\n' "ABC" 5 ''`

Comment: It didn't work with `printf '%s%*s\n' "ABC" 5 '' "DEF"` because `printf` format is one short of total arguments. First `%s` is used for `ABC` and then `%*s` is used to output 5 spaces. But there is no format for `DEF` hence `\n` is appended to both the arguments.

Comment: Understood. Following what you said, I changed to ` printf '%s%*s%s\n' "ABC" 5 '' 'DEF'` and this works. Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 4):

Add another String placeholder for DEF and a new line character:

```
printf '%s%*s%s\n' "ABC" 5 '' "DEF"
```